# WAS dumpNameSpace giving error

Tags: websphere-6.1

When I run the command : `/opt/IBM/Websphere/Appserver/bin/./dumpNameSpace.sh`
I get this error:

```
Getting the initial context
Getting the starting context

==============================================================================
Name Space Dump
   Provider URL: corbaloc:iiop:localhost:2809
   Context factory: com.ibm.websphere.naming.WsnInitialContextFactory
   Requested root context: cell
   Starting context: (top)=ctpCell
   Formatting rules: jndi
   Time of dump: Wed Jan 18 19:04:07 EST 2012
==============================================================================


==============================================================================
Beginning of Name Space Dump
==============================================================================

    1 (top)
    2 (top)/cell                                         javax.naming.Context
    2    Linked to context: ctpCell
    3 (top)/legacyRoot                                   javax.naming.Context
    3    Linked to context: ctpCell/persistent
    4 (top)/nodes                                        javax.naming.Context
    5 (top)/nodes/dmgrNode                               javax.naming.Context
    6 (top)/nodes/dmgrNode/cell                          javax.naming.Context
    6    Linked to context: ctpCell
    7 (top)/nodes/dmgrNode/node                          javax.naming.Context
    7    Linked to context: ctpCell/nodes/dmgrNode
    8 (top)/nodes/dmgrNode/servers                       javax.naming.Context
    9 (top)/nodes/dmgrNode/servers/dmgr                  javax.naming.Context
    9    Linked to URL: corbaloc::hostName:9809/NameServiceServerRoot
   10 (top)/nodes/dmgrNode/nodename                      java.lang.String
   11 (top)/nodes/dmgrNode/domain                        javax.naming.Context
   11    Linked to context: ctpCell
   12 (top)/nodes/ssoNode1                               javax.naming.Context
ERROR: Context "(top)/nodes/ssoNode1" will not be dumped.
       Failure during listBindings() or hasMore() method.
       Exception: javax.naming.PartialResultException: org.omg.CORBA.BAD_PARAM:
        >> SERVER (id=11c328fe, host=hostName) TRACE START:
        >>    org.omg.CORBA.BAD_PARAM: Null Param (5) - any  vmcid: IBM  minor c                                                                                                 ode: 205 completed: Maybe
        >>       at com.ibm.rmi.iiop.CDROutputStream.write_any(CDROutputStream.j                                                                                                 ava:1150)
        >>       at com.ibm.WsnOptimizedNaming.DistBindingDataHelper.write(DistB                                                                                                 indingDataHelper.java:149)
        >>       at com.ibm.WsnOptimizedNaming.DistBindingDataListHelper.write(D                                                                                                 istBindingDataListHelper.java:59)
        >>       at com.ibm.WsnOptimizedNaming._NamingContextImplBase._invoke(_N                                                                                                 amingContextImplBase.java:326)
        >>       at com.ibm.CORBA.iiop.ServerDelegate.dispatchInvokeHandler(Serv                                                                                                 erDelegate.java:627)
        >>       at com.ibm.CORBA.iiop.ServerDelegate.dispatch(ServerDelegate.ja                                                                                                 va:480)
        >>       at com.ibm.rmi.iiop.ORB.process(ORB.java:512)
        >>       at com.ibm.CORBA.iiop.ORB.process(ORB.java:1571)
        >>       at com.ibm.rmi.iiop.Connection.respondTo(Connection.java:2719)
        >>       at com.ibm.rmi.iiop.Connection.doWork(Connection.java:2584)
        >>       at com.ibm.rmi.iiop.WorkUnitImpl.doWork(WorkUnitImpl.java:62)
        >>       at com.ibm.ejs.oa.pool.PooledThread.run(ThreadPool.java:118)
        >>       at com.ibm.ws.util.ThreadPool$Worker.run(ThreadPool.java:1497)
        >> SERVER (id=11c328fe, host=olbbbccld3app21.tsa.bmo.com) TRACE END.
  vmcid: IBM  minor code: 205 completed: Maybe [Root exception is org.omg.CORBA.                                                                                                 BAD_PARAM:
        >> SERVER (id=11c328fe, host=hostName) TRACE START:
        >>    org.omg.CORBA.BAD_PARAM: Null Param (5) - any  vmcid: IBM  minor c                                                                                                 ode: 205 completed: Maybe
        >>       at com.ibm.rmi.iiop.CDROutputStream.write_any(CDROutputStream.j                                                                                                 ava:1150)
        >>       at com.ibm.WsnOptimizedNaming.DistBindingDataHelper.write(DistB                                                                                                 indingDataHelper.java:149)
        >>       at com.ibm.WsnOptimizedNaming.DistBindingDataListHelper.write(D                                                                                                 istBindingDataListHelper.java:59)
        >>       at com.ibm.WsnOptimizedNaming._NamingContextImplBase._invoke(_N                                                                                                 amingContextImplBase.java:326)
        >>       at com.ibm.CORBA.iiop.ServerDelegate.dispatchInvokeHandler(Serv                                                                                                 erDelegate.java:627)
        >>       at com.ibm.CORBA.iiop.ServerDelegate.dispatch(ServerDelegate.ja                                                                                                 va:480)
        >>       at com.ibm.rmi.iiop.ORB.process(ORB.java:512)
        >>       at com.ibm.CORBA.iiop.ORB.process(ORB.java:1571)
        >>       at com.ibm.rmi.iiop.Connection.respondTo(Connection.java:2719)
        >>       at com.ibm.rmi.iiop.Connection.doWork(Connection.java:2584)
        >>       at com.ibm.rmi.iiop.WorkUnitImpl.doWork(WorkUnitImpl.java:62)
        >>       at com.ibm.ejs.oa.pool.PooledThread.run(ThreadPool.java:118)
        >>       at com.ibm.ws.util.ThreadPool$Worker.run(ThreadPool.java:1497)
        >> SERVER (id=11c328fe, host=hostName) TRACE END.
  vmcid: IBM  minor code: 205 completed: Maybe]
   13 (top)/nodes/appNode1                               javax.naming.Context
   14 (top)/nodes/appNode1/nodename                      java.lang.String
   15 (top)/nodes/appNode1/persistent                    javax.naming.Context
   16 (top)/nodes/appNode1/cell                          javax.naming.Context
   16    Linked to context: ctpCell
   17 (top)/nodes/appNode1/nodeAgent                     javax.naming.Context
   17    Linked to context: ctpCell/nodes/appNode1/servers/nodeagent
   18 (top)/nodes/appNode1/node                          javax.naming.Context
   18    Linked to context: ctpCell/nodes/appNode1
   19 (top)/nodes/appNode1/servers                       javax.naming.Context
   20 (top)/nodes/appNode1/servers/cuaServer1            javax.naming.Context
   20    Linked to URL: corbaloc::olbbbccld3app21.tsa.bmo.com:9810/NameServiceServerRoot
   21 (top)/nodes/appNode1/servers/reportServer1         javax.naming.Context
   21    Linked to URL: corbaloc::hostName:9813/NameServiceServerRoot
   22 (top)/nodes/appNode1/servers/batchServer1          javax.naming.Context
   22    Linked to URL: corbaloc::hostName:9812/NameServiceServerRoot
   23 (top)/nodes/appNode1/servers/nodeagent             javax.naming.Context
   24 (top)/nodes/appNode1/servers/nodeagent/servername  java.lang.String
   25 (top)/nodes/appNode1/servers/nodeagent/UserRegistry
   25                                                    com.ibm.websphere.security._UserRegistry_Stub
   26 (top)/nodes/appNode1/servers/nodeagent/thisNode    javax.naming.Context
   26    Linked to context: ctpCell/nodes/appNode1
   27 (top)/nodes/appNode1/servers/nodeagent/SecurityServer
   27                                                    com.ibm.ws.security.server._SecurityServer_Stub
   28 (top)/nodes/appNode1/servers/nodeagent/cell        javax.naming.Context
   28    Linked to context: ctpCell
   29 (top)/nodes/appNode1/domain                        javax.naming.Context
   29    Linked to context: ctpCell
   30 (top)/clusters                                     javax.naming.Context
   31 (top)/clusters/cuaCluster                          javax.naming.Context
   31    Linked to URL: corbaloc::hostName:9810/NameServiceServerRoot
   32 (top)/clusters/ssoCluster                          javax.naming.Context
   32    Linked to URL: corbaloc::hostName:9811/NameServiceServerRoot
   33 (top)/clusters/reportCluster                       javax.naming.Context
   33    Linked to URL: corbaloc::hostName:9813/NameServiceServerRoot
   34 (top)/clusters/batchCluster                        javax.naming.Context
   34    Linked to URL: corbaloc::hostName:9812/NameServiceServerRoot
   35 (top)/persistent                                   javax.naming.Context
   36 (top)/persistent/cell                              javax.naming.Context
   36    Linked to context: ctpCell
   37 (top)/cells                                        javax.naming.Context
   38 (top)/cellname                                     java.lang.String
   39 (top)/deploymentManager                            javax.naming.Context
   39    Linked to URL: corbaloc::olbbbccld3app21:9809/NameServiceServerRoot
   40 (top)/domain                                       javax.naming.Context
   40    Linked to context: ctpCell

==============================================================================
End of Name Space Dump
==============================================================================
```

How to solve this?
 Also is there a way to see the JNDI tree from the admin console (as in weblogic)

Comment: This looks like a product bug. I recommend opening a PMR with IBM.